# Do some cyclic subgroups "partition" a group?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, equivalence-relations, cyclic-groups, set-partition

Is this statement true?

> Let $G=\{g_1,...,g_n\}$ be a finite group. Then there exists some
> $g_{k_1},...,g_{k_j}$ such that $\langle
>  g_{n_1}\rangle\setminus\{1\},...,\langle g_{n_j}\rangle\setminus\{1\}$
> is a partition of $G\setminus \{1\}$.

For example, $S_3=\{1,x,x^2,y,xy,x^2y\}$, where $x=(1,2,3)$ and $y=(1,2)$. Then $\langle x\rangle=\{1,x,x^2\}$, $\langle y\rangle=\{1,y\}$, $\langle xy\rangle=\{1,xy\}$, $\langle x^2y\rangle=\{1,x^2y\}$ are the cyclic subgroups such that, after discarding $1$, they partition $S_3\setminus\{1\}$.

I considered a relation on $G\setminus\{ 1\}$: $a\sim b$ if $a,b\in\langle g_i\rangle$ for some $g_i\in G$. The statement is true if it is an equivalence relation.

When trying to show it is an equivalence relation, I failed to show it is transitive. If $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $a=x^p,b=x^q$ for some $x\in G,p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and$b=y^s,c=y^t$ for some $y\in G,s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$. I guess $a,c$ are in the cyclic subgroup generated by an element of the form $x^uy^o$ but I cannot certify integers $u,o$.

If it turns out that this is false, then what is a counterexample?

Comment: It is false, in general. The first counterexample has order $8$. Since this looks like a homework problem, I will leave you to find a counterexample.

Comment: It's always comforting to me when a false thing can't be proved.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks. I realized Z_4 x Z_2 is a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, that is, although it wasn't the one I was thinking about, which was $Q_8$. The groups $SL_2(q)$ for $q$ odd also have a single element of order $2$, so they fail this quite badly.

Comment: Since this property is inherited by subgroups of $G$, I guess it might be possible to give a complete classification. It holds for cyclic groups and dihedral groups, for example.

Answer (score 2):

This was answered well in the comments, so I'm summarizing here.

Hankai Zeng, the original poster, observed that $G=Z_4\times Z_2$ is a counterexample.
$\def\elt#1#2{(#1, #2)}$
To see this, note that the putative partition into cyclic groups must include a subgroup $S$ that contains $\elt10$, and the same subgroup must also include the element $\elt20$. But similarly, the subgroup $S'$ that contains $\elt11$ must also include $\elt20$, so $S$ and $S'$ intersect nontrivially, which is forbidden unless $S=S'$.  But $\langle \elt10, \elt11\rangle$ generates all of $G$, so if $S=S'$ there is only one part in the partition.  $G$ is not cyclic, so the partition fails to be a partition into cyclic groups.

Similarly, the [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q_8$, also of order 8, is a counterexample.  It has $$Q_8 = \{1, -1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k\}$$ where $$i^2=j^2=k^2 = ijk = -1$$ and $$(-1)^2 = 1.$$  Some part of the partition must contain $i$, and this part must also contain $-1$.  Similarly whatever part contains $j$ must also contain $-1$.  This shows that $i$ and $j$ must be in the same part of the partition.  But $i$ and $j$ together generate $Q_8$ so the partition is trivial.

Comment: Indeed, any abelian group that contains elements of order $p^2$ for some prime $p$, that does not have a single subgroup of order $p$, is a counterexample.